# Non-parametric test for trend

Tags: nonparametric, sas, test-for-trend

I have non-normal data which are sampled from roughly 4 subjects at 4 dose levels.  Is there a nonparametric test for trend I can use in SAS?

Comment: SAS' NPAR1WAY procedure is your best bet. Commonly used nonparametric tests for trend include the Mann-Whitney and the Wilcoxon tests. Here's a link to the SAS support description... https://support.sas.com/rnd/app/stat/procedures/NonparametricAnalysis.html#npar1way

Comment: Are you trying to perform an ANOVA type analysis where you want a trend alternative (e.g. like $\mu_4\geq \mu_3\geq\mu_2\geq\mu_1$ with at least one strict inequality)? Are you treating the subjects as blocks or as random effects?

Comment: I want something approaching testing whether the slope > 0 as the dose gets higher.  I would treat the subjects as random effects.